# Windows.load Function Not working in IE Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

`$(window).load(function () { //Your Function
   });`
I use This Load Function For Apply Some Design After Complete some Web service Process.

It's Work Fine in All Browser But IN IE Not Worked....

Load Function Apply Before Web service Completed

Any Help

my Code Set Up

```
<img src="img/Loading.png" id="image" alt="loading" />
```

---

Show Image Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#image').show();
});
```

//Web service process after Complete

Hide image code

```
$(window).load(function () {
$('#image').hide();
});
```

Comment: can you show me how you have your code set up

Comment: `jQuery.load` function works in IE. The problem is somewhere else. Did you try to debug the problem in console?

Answer (score 0):

try this for IE:

```
window.onload = new function() { //Your Function };
```